# How to find out which php libraries are installed?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, libraries

I have a manual telling me that I need PHP with certain libraries installed.

Is there a command to list all the installed PHP libraries?

How do I know if I have them installed or not?

One would guess that should be a simple command to list them.

It's probably irrelevant to my question, but the needed modules are mysql, xml, mbstring, mcrypt, soap, ladp, gd and curl.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
dpkg --get-selections *php*
```

This will list all the php packages that are currently installed on your system through `apt-get`.